# Pyspark not recognized by intellij even though visible in the configured Python SDK

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

The `Python interpreter` has been selected:

[image]

We can see that the `pyspark` were available (via `pip`) and visible to that python interpreter:

[image]

However the `python` interpreter does not recognize `pyspark` package:

[image]

`pyspark` is the only package that seems to suffer from this issue: `pandas`, `numpy`, `sklearn` etc all work.  So what is different about `pyspark` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the following is not *really* an answer to the original question, it is a *middling* - and only *partial* - workaround.

We need to add several environment variables to the `Run configuration`:

[image]

In particular the `SPARK_HOME`, `PYTHON_SUBMIT_ARGS` (=`pyspark-shell`), and `PYTHONPATH` are needed.

This is inconvenient to need to set for *every* pyspark run configuration .. but presents a last resort.